# RSelenium Chrome webdriver doesn't work with user profile

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I have some existing RSelenium code I am trying to get working with a Chrome Profile.  I am using the code below to open a browser:

```
cprof <- getChromeProfile("C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data",  "Profile 1")
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="80.0.3987.106", port=4451L, extraCapabilities=cprof)
```

But when I run this, Three (3!) new Chrome browser windows open before the following error is displayed in RStudio:

```
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

The puzzling part is that it **does** look like it is getting the **correct** profile, because when I switch between "Profile 1", "Profile 2" and even "Default" in the `getChromeProfile` call, I see the correct user icon in the browser windows that open.  And if I leave off the `extraCapabilities` the browser opens with no problem (using the default "empty" profile).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem